# How to fetch image via GET request in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-maps

I am currently taking the image as a JSON file in `loadImage()`, but I'm busting and would like to know which would be the right mode. Another thing to know is that I get the `photo_reference` parameter only after the first `fetch`. I'm using  Google Maps Place Photo API. From the first fetch, I get a JSON file.

My code so far:

```
const CardResturant = ({ resturant }) => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [info, setInfo] = useState([]);

  const [imagePlace, setImage] = useState([]);
  const [isLoadImage, setLoadImage] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
    fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=${resturant.id}&key=KEY`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setInfo(json);
        loadImage(json?.result?.photos[0].photo_reference);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(true));
  }, []);

  const loadImage = (photo_reference) => {
    setLoadImage(false);
    fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=100&photo_reference=${photo_reference}&key=KEY`
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((photo) => setImage(photo))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoadImage(true));
  };

  return (
    <View>
      {!isLoading ? (
        <Text>LOADING</Text>
      ) : (
        <View>
          <View>
            <Image ??help?? />
          </View>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `res.json()` to parse an image. It should be `res.blob()`. That has been said, assuming you are trying to fetch one image, you could do it like so:

```js
const [imagePlace, setImage] = useState(""); // initialize it to an empty string
```

```js
const loadImage = async (photo_reference) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=100&photo_reference=${photo_reference}&key=KEY`
    )
    const data = await res.blob();
    setImage(URL.createObjectURL(data));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
};
```

I'm using `async/await` just to have a better-looking code. Your approach with `then()` would work as well. Finally, change your JSX for rendering the image to:

```js
{imagePlace ? (
  <Image source={{ uri: imagePlace }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
) : (
  <></>
)}
```