# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth) in ReactNative(Typescript) while fetching bytearray from Api response?

Tags: react-native, mobile-application

While I'm trying to convert byte-array image data into Base64 string it throws  "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error.

I'm assuming that ,  if byte-array length  is over 100000 then this error is showing because other api data are working fine.

Here you can check code block where i'm having issue.

Thanks in Advance

```
const response = await fetch(`API URL`, {
  method: "GET",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    Accept: "*/*",
  },
});
if (!response.ok) {
  throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
}
const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
const base64String = Base64.btoa(
  String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(buffer)),
);
setDataURL("data:image/png;base64," + base64String);
```

I did try multiple way...

Comment: I think you use loadmore to reduce render array item

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fetch image via GET request in React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73545401/how-to-fetch-image-via-get-request-in-react-native)